# Why does my sprite work with % but not with px?

Tags: html, css

I created this sprite with four identically sized rectangles:
Top left red
Adjacent to the right black
Adjacent below the red is blue
Adjacent below the blue is green

[image]

My first code to retrieve each rectangle worked perfectly. Here I’m retrieving the blue rectangle.

```css
#red #blue #green #black {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#red {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 77%;
  height: 54%;
  object-position: 0 0;
}

#blue {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 77%;
  height: 54%;
  object-position: 0 25%;
}

#green {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 77%;
  height: 54%;
  object-position: 0 50%;
}

#black {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 77%;
  height: 54%;
  object-position: 35% 0;
}

div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 4%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <img id="blue" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am1zA.jpg">

</div>
```

When I changed the height, width & position to use px, I could only get the red rectangle. If I try and get any of the others, all that gets displayed is the empty yellow div.

```css
#red #blue #green #black {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#red {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
  object-position: 0 0;
}

#blue {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
  object-position: 0 378px;
}

#green {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
  object-position: 0 756px;
}

#black {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
  object-position: 375px 0;
}

div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 4%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="blue" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am1zA.jpg">
</div>
```

If I change the height and width of red to 400px, when I try to retrieve it I can see a slice of the black rectangle to its right, and a slice of the blue one below it.
[image]

Comment: The selector `#red #blue #green #black` will only select an element with the id "black" that's within an element with the id "green" that's within an element with the id "blue" that's within an element with the id "red". Use commas, not spaces if you want all of the selectors to apply.

Comment: With reference to @Heretic Monkey's correct comment. you should try `#red, #blue, #green, #black { ` with commas to distinguish different individual selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You got the sign wrong. I also moved the common code to the common rule and removed some code that made no difference.

```css
#red, #blue, #green, #black {
  object-fit: none;
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
}

#red {
  object-position: 0 0;
}

#blue {
  object-position: 0 -384px;
}

#green {
  object-position: 0 -762px;
}

#black {
  object-position: -392px 0;
}

div {
  width: 375px;
  height: 378px;
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="green" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am1zA.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: That solved my problem, but now I can’t correctly use the sprite as a background image to a <div>. No matter which image colour I choose, the background image displayed is always red.

Comment: The code given here was to fix the problem as presented in the question (namely, using `object-position` to position an image within an `img` container. If you're using a background image, you'd need to use the specific requirements for the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property.